# Ubuntu 14.10 can't connect to "Wireless N" signals

Tags: wireless

I am using Ubuntu 14.10 on an Asus laptop -- and I can't connect to my wireless router if I have it set to the 2.4GHz Wireless N mode. And, worse, it has a difficult time connecting to my router if it is set at Mixed NG.  Oddly, using "sudo iwlist scan" it can see routers with N -- it just can't connect.

I have done a number of searches online for this problem, which seems common, but the solutions all seem to involve a different wireless card, an outdated version of Ubuntu, a different kernel, or has a conf file that doesn't exist on mine.

Here are a few quick specs that other users have posted:

**Kernel**

```
Ubuntu 3.16.0-28.38-generic 3.16.7-ckt1
```

**Q501LA:~$ sudo iwconfig**

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"dd_wrt"  Nickname:"<WIFI@REALTEK>"
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: C0:C1:C0:96:05:AF   
      Bit Rate:72.2 Mb/s   Sensitivity:0/0  
      Retry:off   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=100/100  Signal level=66/100  Noise level=0/100
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

**Q501LA:~$ sudo  lspci -v**

```
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 0c)
Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 200f
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 60
I/O ports at e000 [size=256]
Memory at f7d00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
Memory at f0000000 (64-bit, prefetchable) [size=16K]
Capabilities: [40] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [50] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [70] Express Endpoint, MSI 01
Capabilities: [b0] MSI-X: Enable- Count=4 Masked-
Capabilities: [d0] Vital Product Data
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Virtual Channel
Capabilities: [160] Device Serial Number 48-43-36-44-68-4c-e0-00
Capabilities: [170] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Kernel driver in use: r8169

03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
Flags: bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 255
Memory at f7c00000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8K]
Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
Capabilities: [140] Device Serial Number 0c-8b-fd-ff-ff-6a-1f-fd
Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
Capabilities: [154] Vendor Specific Information: ID=cafe Rev=1 Len=014 <?>
```

This is making it really hard to use Ubuntu -- as everytime I take my laptop somewhere that uses the N Wireless mode, I can't access the network.  In addition, I can't access my Android's WiFi hotspot, because it is N. Hopefully, someone out there has an idea how to fix this!!!

*One side note*:  Although I am using an external USB dongle, [an Edimax](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY), because the internal card was not receiving signals very strongly, this problem was the same with the built-in Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless-N 7260 card. Also, I made sure that my router is set to send 2.4 GHz wireless N, because the Edimax cannot access 5GHz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks SO MUCH for your help **Jeremy31**.  The exact suggestion didn't work.  But  I googled "11n_disable=8" because I thought it should be "11n_disable=0," but didn't want to respond with a stupid comment if I was wrong (which I was).  Anyway, that led me to [this similar solution for a different problem](http://bernaerts.dyndns.org/linux/74-ubuntu/322-ubuntu-trusty-intel-centrino-6235-slow):

```
echo options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8 | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-11n.conf
echo options iwlwifi bt_coex_active=0 | sudo tee -a /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi-11n.conf
```

I did this, rebooted, and it worked.  I am now connected to my wireless router, which is in 2.4GHz N only mode.

Thanks again!

Comment: Nice to hear you got it working.  If you wish, please update your post on ubuntuforums.org